# Checking if data has spatial definition?

Tags: python, arcpy

I am trying to check if my data has a valid spatial reference and then check if its projected am running it an error saying can't execute:
My code:

```
import arcpy
import os, sys, traceback, shutil
import numpy as np

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

try:
    outputfolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    inputraster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

    #check to see if the arcinfo license is on
    if arcpy.CheckProduct("ArcInfo")=="Available":
        continue
    else:
        arcpy.AddError("An ArcInfo license is required to run this tool")
        sys.exit()

    #set the Progressor
    arcpy.SetProgessor("step","Checking input requirements....",0,9,1) 

    #Process :create an out put folder
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(outputfolder,"output.gdb")
    outputgdb = outputfolder + "\\output.gdb"+ os.step

    #create path to store raster data
    flooded = outputfolder +"floodedarea"

    #check to see if the inputs are in the same projection
    desccs_ras = arcpy.Describe(inputraster).SpatialReference
    desccs_fc = arcpy.Describe(fc).SpatialReference
    if desccs_ras.name,desccs_fc.name ="Unknown":
        arcpy.AddMessage("Your data does not have a defined spatial reference")
    else:
        if desccs_ras.projectionName == desccs_fc.projectionName:
            continue
        else:
            arcpy.AddError("The input Data should be in the same projection")
            sys.exit()
        del desccs_fc,desccs_ras
```

I don't know what is wrong .Please help.The error I get is:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (zerowayRule.py, line 32)
```

Comment: Is that all the code?  If you have a `try:`, you need to have the `except:` as well.  http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/error-handling/python-try-and-except  If you are missing code, please add it.

Comment: are you getting an error message? I so, would you be able to add it to your question?

Comment: @RichardMorgan i have 'except:'  but it the code stops on the If statement checking the spatial reference

Comment: `if desccs_ras.name,desccs_fc.name ="Unknown":` cant be correct. For example you are missing an AND (?) and = should be ==?

Comment: @BERA  I noticed, corrected it and It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 32 is `if desccs_ras.name,desccs_fc.name ="Unknown":`

This code cant be correct. For example you are missing an `AND` (?) and `=` should be `==`.